# Chromebook selecting items for Drive and upload fails for Google-docs files

Tags: chromebook

I created a simple upload form and open this on my Chromebook. It shows me the "Drive" by default. When I select the PNG and PDF and upload it to my server, it all works fine. But When selecting the `.gsheet`, `.gslides` or the `.gdoc` it results in an upload of 0kb. As you can see in the screenshot there is no "sizefile" known also when opening the drive.

[image: Drive HTML5]

Probably because it's not "converted" to a file or something? When I go to my original Google Drive on a Macbook and click on the file to download, it results in a converted download response.. How can I achieve it to get a "converted" file also when selected via the default HTML5 interface `<input type="file" name="attachment" />`?